# Java EE SDK 8 don't find JDK EE 8

Tags: java

My project have been developing about JSP , servlets , applets... I am using intelliJ idea version 2018.1.5 and my project cann't continue configuration because it missed JDK EE 8 , I try to downloaded JDK EE 8 on page oracle and pages another but i cannot find this JDK

could you please guide me how to download the java EE jdk to fit with Java sdk ee 8?

Answer (score 1):

Start with installing [Java 8 SE JDK](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and then add other libraries gradually

Comment: excuse me ! I 'm finding JDK for EE not SE , I try to found on https://www.oracle.com page but not found JDK EE 8 , please help me !

Comment: This is because there is no such JDK anymore. Please look at the [History subsection at Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition). As of now this is a specification, that has different implementations, incl. a reference one by Eclipse foundation

Answer (score 1):

if you using maven
add depency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>8.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

for web only:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>8.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

gradle:

```
provided group: 'javax', name: 'javaee-api', version: '8.0'
```